# How serious a problem can outgassing of satellites be?

Tags: cubesat, outgassing

As I was reading [the Cubesat standard](https://www.cubesat.org/s/cds_rev13_final2.pdf), one of requirements is low outgassing "to prevent contamination of other spacecraft". It also gives a link to a NASA-approved list of low outgassing materials.

Is this an actual problem that can be a hurdle and has caused problems in the past, or is it a mere formality like "don't send stuff that will boil off in vacuum, spraying everything around with droplets"?

Comment: For example I've noticed some superglues (cyanoacrylate) produce a vapour that can fog nearby glass or acrylic. Perhaps further outgassing later under a vacuum could cause problems for another spacecraft in the same dispenser...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its not a mere formality it is unfortunately one of those things that makes satellites expensive. However I wouldn't be surprised if all kinds of nominally incompatible materials have already been exposed in cubesat missions.  **EDIT** This report might be useful background: [NASA contamination control report 1996](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19960044619.pdf)

It could in principle affect other parts of the cubesat or in the shorter term other cubesats in the dispenser or other systems outside a cubesat dispenser. A consequence of the dispenser being an enclosure is that there will still be  some leak paths and these become the main out-gassing vent routes. The time for this to occur might limit the worst of the hazard to the host cubesat.

The mechanisms of adhesion to other surfaces are varied and include condensation on cool surfaces and also UV ionisation and electro-static return to a surface not on a direct flight path. **EDIT** The link I added above has a short section on this, section 2.3.1.2.2.2, figure reproduced below:
[image]

Note however the reference goes on to say that this particular mechanism is believed to be much more of a problem at GEO altitudes because the plasma screening distance is much greater than at LEO.

Outgassing products can be water vapour, most solid objects have a dose of trapped moisture, or something more destructive. See this article http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sat/hs-702.htm regarding ouggassing from solar arrays. It says:

> The first version of the 702 used solar arrays with concentrators. These concentrators tended to early fogging, as due to an inherent design flaw the outgassing of the solar cells was higher than expected. This fogging lead to much reduced lifetime.

The latter satellites all weighed several tonnes and I suspect cost over a billion $ between them.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few recorded incidents of spacecraft contamination caused by outgassing.

On Cassini, some haze was noted in test photographs after launch; this was thought to be due to some outgassing material near the camera itself. It was removed after several attempts using the camera's heaters:

[Cassini Imaging Science report](http://www.ciclops.org/sci/docs/CassiniImagingScience.pdf), 2004, p.475-476.

On Stardust, the navigation camera became contaminated after launch. Again spacecraft heaters were used to eventually clear the problem:

[NASA page on Stardust's cameras](http://stardust.jpl.nasa.gov/news/vision.html)

Also the [Stardust "Lessons Learned"](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140001406.pdf) report mentions this and an additional problem with sample collection:

> ...However, despite these precautions the
>   Stardust spacecraft outgassing was sufficient to degrade
>   camera operations, and the aerogel capture media
>   was significantly contaminated during manufacture.
>   We also never completely solved the problem of
>   defining useful limits for organic contaminants of
>   spacecraft hardware, which haunts us as we rather unexpectedly
>   captured primitive cometary organics.

Comment: Did my answer draw your attention to that paragraph from the Stardust Lessons Learned?

Comment: @called2voyage no I haven't seen your answer - is it to a different question somewhere? (In this particular answer I'm just linking to the only two cases I was able to find.)

Comment: I just thought it was a funny coincidence. I happened to quote this exact passage before: http://space.stackexchange.com/a/15516/58

Comment: @called2voyage thanks - interesting question. Of course [Osiris-Rex](http://www.asteroidmission.org/) is using a completely different sample collection system, using inert gas and a metal container, so I think the lessons have been learned...

Comment: If I understand the answers correctly for now, outgassing is only a problem if the gas condenses afterwards. If it remains gas and vents into void, that's not a problem.

Comment: @SF. if the gas hangs around and affects readings of sensitive instruments (mass spectrometer etc?) that might be a problem too. I wasn't able to find any examples of that though... it probably diffuses as you say.

Comment: @SF. The electrostatic return principle operates as follows - 1. in the transition from sea level pressure to near vacuum some gas leaves the material that carried it into orbit 2. some of that gas is immediately ionised by solar ultra-violet light 3. the satellite has already been building up its own, different, charge distribution because of the mix of energetic particles, offset a little by the same UV photo-emission 4. where there are opposite charges the ionised off-gas products are attracted back to the satellite and stick.  I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: Not to forget [ESAs Gaia mission](http://blogs.esa.int/gaia/2014/06/16/preliminary-analysis-of-stray-light-impact-and-strategies/), which seemingly has an issue with water vapor.

Answer (score 2):

> How serious a problem can outgassing of satellites be?

Serious.

Outgassing is discussed in the following questions and/or their answers.

I'm going to propose that this is not a link-only answer as these are not external links. To try to summarize **all these different serious problems** related to outgassing would be a several thousand word copy/paste montage that would not be updated when information in all these other posts may be revised, updated, or new answers emerge.

So I'm going to propose that the sheer size of this list of other posts in this site as support that outgassing can be a serious problem.

- [What are the common space application adhesives used in Earth orbiting satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9046/12102)
- [Why is the Aeolus space laser losing power so quickly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36151/12102)
- [Do things get dirty in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17196/12102)
- [What are the common space application adhesives used in Earth orbiting satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9046/12102)
- [How is the atmosphere in the pressurized housing of ISS' HDEV cameras managed? Outgassing addressed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34531/12102)
- [What is the "space grease" used to lubricate the ISS robotic arm? What are the material considerations for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39520/12102)
- [Were solar concentrators on HS-702 just a stop-gap measure until triple-junction PV cells were available?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21410/12102)
- [ViaSat's 18 kW solar array - largest ever for a commercial telecom satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21749/12102)
- [Hows does "Glenn Research Center's sapphire refractive secondary concentrator" work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30231/12102)
- [Advantages/disadvantages of wood for surface of cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53775/12102)
- [Do reaction wheels generally run in vacuum, or are they pressurized? Sealed or vented?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18874/12102)
- [Why are some reaction wheels sealed with low pressure gas, others with vacuum?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18924/12102)
- [Do electronics and mechanical components work in a vacuum or require a sealed controlled atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18858/12102)
- [Do vacuum-grade oils and greases trivially solve the "lubricants don't work in space, cold welding happens" problem (for short to moderate duration)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41879/12102)