# Do vacuum-grade oils and greases trivially solve the "lubricants don't work in space, cold welding happens" problem (for short to moderate duration)?

Tags: materials, vacuum, environment, reliability

(Related: [How is the unwanted cold welding prevented in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/how-is-the-unwanted-cold-welding-prevented-in-space))

I've often seen talk about fairly simple mechanical devices (hand tools, simple handheld power tools, firearms, etc) being unlikely to work if not specially modified for use in the vacuum of space because of the evaporation of lubricants and the tendency for metal to cold-weld. The modifications tend to focus on high-tech treatments such as dry lubricants, Teflon bearings, and special solid lubricant coatings. This is especially pronounced in writings for a popular audience, such as articles about NASA's handheld EVA power tools.

However, modern industry provides plenty of vacuum-grade oils and grease bases such as silicones (such as the wretched and ubiquitous turquoise tube Dow grease), perfluoropolyethers (such as Fomblin and Krytox), or low-vapor-pressure hydrocarbons (such as Apiezon grease). These have vapor pressures at 25 deg C of well under 10E-6 torr, and often maintain low vapor pressures of under a few millitorr at high temperatures. For lubrication purposes they may be made into greases containing colloidal PTFE, moly, graphite, or boron nitride.

Could simple mechanical devices designed for commercial-grade use on Earth be "vacuumized" by re-lubricating them with such greases and oils, and work reliably in space for some hours or days? Clearly this isn't suitable for long-duration unmanned satellites or safety-critical anything, but is it enough to mitigate the basic issue and make equipment usable without redesign?

Comment: The wheels of the Soviet lunar rovers did not use any lubricant. The secret was in the material that formed the glass film between the rubbing surfaces.

Comment: And we have the igus corporation endlessly plugging their dry-running plastic bearings, though IDK if they work well in vacuum. I'm more focused on equipment designed using conventional principles for terrestrial mechanicals.

Comment: related space-lube posts: [What is the “space grease” used to lubricate the ISS robotic arm? What are the material considerations for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39520/12102) and [Do reaction wheels generally run in vacuum, or are they pressurized? Sealed or vented?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18874/12102) and [Why are some reaction wheels sealed with low pressure gas, others with vacuum?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18924/12102)

Comment: @uhoh definitely related but I think this is a pretty distinct question.

Comment: @ikrase I agree. When people put "related" items in comments it helps to bring in context, data and insight that may be helpful towards an answer, and it adds these to the Linked Item list that appears in the right sidebar. In other SE sites "related" comments are feared because they can trigger indiscriminate close voting, but that's generally not the case here.

Comment: @uhoh I'm sorry, that was sorta what I was scared about.

Comment: I suspect that some of it is that, by the time you disassemble, clean, and relube a Earth-grade tool you might as well have done it right in the first place, particularly since you can't drop by your local home repair store very easily. All those greases you reference, which I have long experience using in vacuum, really aren't that good a lubricant for something with reasonable torque at 1000s of rpms. The ones that are good aren't just a squirt-on-and-good-to-go process.

Comment: bear i mind that vacuum is just one of the problems, temperature and atomic oxygen also try to spoil your toys

Comment: Maybe no lubricant is the way to go. Your typical train car wheels don't use lubricant either.